# What is the encoding protocol for passphrase protected RSA private keys?

Tags: rsa, openssl, encoding, ssh

What is the protocol used to encode an RSA key protected with a passphrase?

If I generate an RSA key with

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

and do:

```
head ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I get:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,83F1F6710FBD0610A70A04F5ABDE4114

<base64 data>
```

What encoding protocol does this use?

For RSA private keys not protected by a passphrase, they are encoded in Base64 ASN.1 and the structure is documented here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-A.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file format, which is used by OpenSSH below 7.8 by default for RSA, is actually defined and implemented by OpenSSL, which documents it fairly tersely on the [man page for a group of library routines including `PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey.html) near the bottom at the heading "PEM ENCRYPTION FORMAT". Quoting for convenience and because of many Stack-ers' linkophobia:

> The line beginning with Proc-Type contains the version and the protection on the encapsulated data. The line beginning DEK-Info contains two comma separated values: the encryption algorithm name as used by EVP_get_cipherbyname() and an initialization vector used by the cipher encoded as a set of hexadecimal digits. After those two lines is the base64-encoded encrypted data.
>
> The encryption key is derived using EVP_BytesToKey(). The cipher's initialization vector is passed to EVP_BytesToKey() as the salt parameter. Internally, PKCS5_SALT_LEN bytes of the salt are used (regardless of the size of the initialization vector). The user's password is passed to EVP_BytesToKey() using the data and datal parameters. Finally, the library uses an iteration count of 1 for EVP_BytesToKey().
>
> The key derived by EVP_BytesToKey() along with the original initialization vector is then used to decrypt the encrypted data. The iv produced by EVP_BytesToKey() is not utilized or needed, and NULL should be passed to the function.

EVP_BytesToKey itself is documented on [its own man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_BytesToKey.html) and covered in numerous Stack questions or answers including [one of my longer ones](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption) (which is actually about commandline `enc` but the EVP_BytesToKey part applies additionally to 'legacy-PEM' encryption).

The decrypted plaintext is the same as the unencrypted form, PKCS1 (rfc8017 et pred).

[The ursine answer to this Q over in security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39279/stronger-encryption-for-ssh-keys) also covers this and related formats in some detail.

For clarity note there are many other file formats for RSA keys, even within OpenSSL and OpenSSH much less other software; this is *a* scheme for some passphrase-protected RSA private keys but not *the* scheme for all such keys.