# AES Password Based Key Derivation Iterations

Tags: aes, keys, key-derivation, openssl, sha-512

I have been writing my own implementation of the Advanced Encryption Standard with cipher block chaining in python3 for the last several months, mimicking the OpenSSL command line interface. I can successfully encrypt a message or binary with the OpenSSL implementation of AES and then decrypt it with my python3 program (and vice versa).

I am currently working on PBKDF1 SHA-512 Key Iterations.

OpenSSL generates the key and IV for the password “Sparky” using PBKDF1 SHA-512 like so:

OpenSSL command to use to follow along is this:

```
printf "hi" | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -md sha512 -p -S 436172616D656C00 -k “Sparky”
```

which means that

```
salt=436172616D656C00
key=D0F4428B02B161F125FF3FA1FDD98AFE 
IV=6F26A9F743FAD01BBC68417A398359A6
```

In python3, the same Key and IV can be obtained like this:

```
import hashlib

salt = "436172616D656C00"
passwd = "Sparky”.encode(“utf-8")
salted = passwd + bytes.fromhex(salt)
Key = hashlib.sha512(salted).hexdigest()[0:32]
IV = hashlib.sha512(salted).hexdigest()[32:64]
```

The key and IV can be found in substrings of the SHA-512 hash.

---

So I’m not having trouble obtaining the Key and the IV without iterations, but I can’t figure out how to generate the next iteration of the `Key` (-iter 1)

According to several sources on the internet the iteration function hashes the resultant hash `n` times. I think something else or something additional is going though because I have tried to hash `Hash#0` and the resultant hash does not contain the expected strings for the `Key` and `IV`.

So the result of the same OpenSSL command above but with `-iter 1` added yields:

```
printf "hi" | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -md sha512 -p -S 436172616D656C00 -k "Sparky" -iter 1
```

results in:

```
salt=436172616D656C00
key=6354F3AE1EEF92EAE4406759A5882B46 
IV=8ACE6C6AE7E1EBDEE45342D0C9087422
```

`Hash0` (the SHA-512 hash without iterations) in this example is

```
d0f4428b02b161f125ff3fa1fdd98afe6f26a9f743fad01bbc68417a398359a675fe9c7bbf87315f7e4d2b8ef40e578a86eec2acdd95511329af2a9d69f59e76
```

If I were to take this hash which I know to be good for the 0-th iteration, and hash it again, I would get:

```
35841649790d6ce2d0ac2b3fe338aba5121858494006aa098f84e06f21587b77adf14f1c5c0a1530db628acfd5d6123d46e449b9619a41a5a6e32ab9230a31e4
```

And according to the OpenSSL command with `-iter 1` set, the hash should start with

```
6354F3AE1EEF92EAE4406759A5882B468ACE6C6AE7E1EBDEE45342D0C9087422
```

If you would like to see my code, I can upload it to github or my virtual private server and share it.

Comment: "I have been reverse engineering and writing the Advanced Encryption Standard" - It is a well known standard since more than 20 years. What do you mean by reverse engineering AES? Of were you reverse engineering thy Python library? Again, why? The source code of many Python libraries is open source, means you can get the source code for free and there is nothing to reverse engineer.

Comment: I wanted to write AES from scratch (besides the Rcon, SubBytes, and Mix Columns vectors) to see if I could. I started by programming the ShiftRows step. Then I wrote the SubBytes step, then the mixcolumns step, then key schedule. Once that was done I added cipher block chaining because it was electronic code book at the time. A month ago I added Sha512 key derivation and salting. Now I’m trying to add the key iteration feature for KDF1. I wrote my own library of code and the goal is to figure out what OpenSSL is doing when it iterates through derived keys.

Comment: "the goal is to figure out what OpenSSL is doing when it iterates through derived keys" - Just look at the source code of OpenSSL and you will see that.

Comment: OpenSSL isn’t a python library it’s a compiled C program.

Comment: I haven't said it is Python. I said it is open source. See [the Git repository of OpenSSL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl).

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will look through it and OpenSSL.org thoroughly.

Comment: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_BytesToKey.html.        

The key and IV is derived by concatenating D_1, D_2, etc until enough data is available for the key and IV. D_i is defined as:

data is a buffer containing datal bytes which is used to derive the keying data. count is the iteration count to use. The derived key and IV will be written to key and iv respectively.



D_i = HASH^count(D_(i-1) || data || salt)

Comment: By the way, that `EVP_BytesToKey` is not a PBKDF described in PKCS#5 (PBE) which defines PBKDF1 and PBKDF2; it's similar but proprietary to OpenSSL.

Comment: I propose we assume the OP wanted to write: _For several months, I've been reverse-engineering openssl's Advanced Encryption Standard with cipher block chaining encryption, and rewriting it in python3._ @mentallurg

Comment: You are correct @fgrieu. Thanks Maarten. Thanks for the pointer mentallurg. .. The PKCS#5 rfc doesn’t share anything useful about derived key iterations. Thanks for the discussion. You guys sound like cool dudes .

Comment: OP: specifying `enc ... -iter 1` _automatically uses PBKDF2_ (which uses HMAC) and not `EVP_BytesToKey` (which uses a plain hash); see the man page on your system or [on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html). @MaartenBodewes: in some cases including this one `EVP_BytesToKey` is _almost_ PBKDF1; see my comparison at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption/#35614 .

Comment: Actually if you are paying attention, you'll notice that `enc ... -iter 1` in 1.1.1 does NOT give the warning about 'deprecated key derivation used' which should clue you in that PBKDF2 _was_ used (and `EVP_BytesTokey` was not)

Comment: OK, interesting that they didn't use a more explicit switch for that, very confusing. It's not PBKDF1 though, which the author put in the question / comments, so I'm still happy that I brought it up, even though I was wrong. B345T, you can lookup the algorithm descriptions of PBKDF1/2 in PKCS#5 RFC.

Comment: Thank you Maarten and @dave_thompson_085 for the input. You are correct. Today I discovered and confirmed that OpenSSL uses a default 10,000 iterations when -pbkdf2 is specified. Also I found the comparison link that you provided to be extremely informative.

Comment: Looking back at this I think this would be more appropriate on [so] but I guess it doesn't do any harm where it is. Please do not use this as an example of what is on topic on [crypto.se] though.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for all of the excellent help. I am happy to say that with your help I have found the answer to my initial question and more.
The code below accepts a [string] password, [hex string] salt, [int] key size, and [int] iteration count, and returns a tuple containing the correct key and IV for PBKDF2. OpenSSL PBKDF2 uses 10,000 iterations by default. Leave the salt in the command as double quotes if there is no salt.

Proof:

printf "Today is a good day!" | openssl enc -aes-192-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -S 436172616d656c73 -k "Sparky" -p

results in:

salt=436172616D656C73

key=37A12300EF8D3442B266B41172154DFE0836803C4257AFB6

iv=E2FC1F1DF27AB4A6F303EDD6537EEE53

The same salt, key, and IV can be obtained by using the code and class below:

from pbkdf2 import kdf

key, iv = kdf.pbkdf2(“Sparky”,”436172616D656C73”,192,10000)

results in:

key=37A12300EF8D3442B266B41172154DFE0836803C4257AFB6
iv=E2FC1F1DF27AB4A6F303EDD6537EEE53

“Sparky” is the password
“436172616D656C73” is the salt
192 is the AES-CBC key size
10,000 is the number of hmac iterations (pbkdf2)

And here is the Python3 code (pbkdf2.py).

Import hashlib

import hmac

class kdf:

```
def pbkdf2(passwd, salt, size, iterations):


    dictionary = {128:((0,32),(32,64)), 192:((0,48),(48,80)), 256:((0,64),(64,96))}

    k = b = hmac.new(passwd.encode("utf-8"), bytes.fromhex(salt) + b'\x00\x00\x00\x01' if len(salt) > 0 else b'\x00\x00\x00\x01', hashlib.sha512).digest()

    for i in range(2, iterations + 1):
        b = hmac.new(passwd.encode("utf-8"), b, hashlib.sha512).digest()
        k = bytes(i ^ j for i, j in zip(k, b))


    key = k.hex()[dictionary.get(size)[0][0]:dictionary.get(size)[0][1]]
    _iv = k.hex()[dictionary.get(size)[1][0]:dictionary.get(size)[1][1]]

    return key,_iv
```

Comment: FYI [Python 3.4 up hashlib provides pbkdf2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#key-derivation) which usually is optimized

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I’m writing this program for my resume so I’m trying to write all of the code from scratch.