# How to encrypt a text file in a portable manner based solely on a password?

Tags: openssl, password-based-encryption

I used to use openssl aes-256-cbc, but the problem I have with this is when I try to decrypt in a different version of the distro it fails, as if it depends also on some internal key or something, instead of depending solely on the password. So I have to keep a different encrypted file for each version of the distro, which is annoying and bad.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because software recommendations belong on SuperUser, not here.

Comment: That said, I'd recommend `age` for such use. https://age-encryption.org

Comment: @SAIPeregrinus I asked the question in SuperUser and it's already closed for being offtopic. You guys are really something special.

Comment: I've seen what happened over there, @ChocoDeveloper. That is absolutely brilliant, and classic Stack Exchange material. LOL.

Comment: That's why I commented with my recommendation. I figure they might be jerks about it. :(

Comment: `openssl enc` with the same arguments (except for `-e/-d` and excluding `-pbkdf2` or `-iter` in 1.1.1), and assuming no password/phrase character encodes differently, should be compatible across platforms EXCEPT between versions 1.1.0 up and those below, and those can be fixed with `-md $hash`. For (long) details see (my) https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption/#35614 . That said, `openssl enc` is _weak_, and there are alternatives like gpg.

Comment: have you considered LUKS/2 and `cryptsetup`? this gives you stronger password-based KDFs, (addressing *one of* @dave_thompson_085 's concerns) and relative portability, but with a smaller header as a tradeoff  //  `cryptsetup --type=luks2 --pbkdf=argon2id --pbkdf-memory=1048576 --pbkdf-parallel=4 --pbkdf-force-iterations=8 --hash=sha384 --luks2-metadata-size=16k --luks2-keyslots-size=$((512*1024)) --master-key-file=trial_master_key --uuid=12345678-abcd-1234-abcd-0123456789ab luksFormat /dev/new_luks_partition1` .. I read somewhere that you can also perform `cryptsetup` on a loopback device.

Comment: also, instead of using `openssl` to produce the output, you might consider using it to secure a random key that you'd used previously to encrypt a file (eg, with `7z`)  see `openssl pkeyutl -derive`

Comment: and, off topic, you will most likely have *Libsodium*, and probably even `python3` installed, which allows for using [*Pysodium*](https://github.com/stef/pysodium/blob/master/pysodium/__init__.py#L596) to secure the file/output with [*crypto boxes*](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/public-key_cryptography/authenticated_encryption)